# Google Drive API for receiving access request notification

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate with Google Drive such that I can receive a notification whenever someone tries to request access for any file in my drive. But, I could not find any such API for that.

I have integrated with Google Drive `Watch Changes` API, but it doesn't push any event for access requests, otherwise, it works fine. I have also checked `List Changes` and `Query Activity` api whether it has any change for such case, but I could not find any such change/activity.

I found out that Slack can receive such notifications which means it is possible somehow. Kindly help, if you know how can it be done.

Comment: Hi there, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your goal is to record each time that someone opens any file in your Drive. If my assumption is correct, then you could use [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) to accomplish your goal. You should create an [`onOpen()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) trigger that saves the user interaction (you may want to send yourself an email with [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)), and apply it to every file that you want to monitor. You can take these [project management examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/samples/manage) as a reference. Please, ask me any additional doubt about this approach.

Comment: No i think the goal is to get access requests via API, not when someone open a file.